# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: shift_type_ids, unit_shift_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, rails-activerecord, mass-assignment

I'm trying to have a single form that creates a Unit in a hospital and you can select shift_types that apply to that Unit in the UnitShiftTypes table.  I have has_many and :through UnitShiftTypes between Units and ShiftTypes. It seems to throw an error each and every time. I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@unit) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :number %>
    <%= f.fields_for :unit_shift_type do |ff| %>
      <%= f.select :shift_type_ids, ShiftType.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id, ]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
      <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :hospital_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

unit.rb

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :hospital
has_many :unit_users, :dependent => :restrict
has_many :unit_shift_types
has_many :users, :through => :unit_users, :dependent => :restrict
has_many :shift_types, :through => :unit_shift_types

attr_accessible :hospital_id, :name, :number, :unit_id, :unit_shift_types_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :unit_shift_types

validates_presence_of :hospital_id, :name, :number
validates_uniqueness_of :number, :scope => :hospital_id, :message => "is already associated with this Hospital."
end
```

unit_shift_type.rb

```
class UnitShiftType < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :shift_type
belongs_to :unit

attr_accessible :shift_type_id, :unit_id

validates_presence_of :shift_type_id, :unit_id
validates_uniqueness_of :shift_type_id, :scope => :unit_id, :message => "is already associated with this Unit."
end
```

shift_type.rb

```
class ShiftType < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :unit_shift_types

attr_accessible :created_by_id, :enabled, :end_time, :name, :start_time
validates_presence_of :start_time, :end_time, :name, :created_by_id

end
```

units_controller.rb

```
# POST /units
# POST /units.json
def create
  @unit = Unit.new(params[:unit])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @unit.save
      format.html { redirect_to @unit, notice: 'Unit was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @unit, status: :created, location: @unit }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @unit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PUT /units/1
# PUT /units/1.json
def update
  @unit = Unit.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @unit.update_attributes(params[:unit])
      format.html { redirect_to @unit, notice: 'Unit was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @unit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Request Parameter:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CnIZCDbEVNr/B8fby2La8ibvtQtjycwO/BD0mQ2sOw4=", "unit"=>{"name"=>"1", "number"=>"1", "shift_type_ids"=>["", "1"], "unit_shift_type"=>{"user_id"=>""}, "hospital_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Unit", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"units"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the existing shift_types while creating a new unit and you are using the shift_type_ids then you do not need to specify nested attributes. Anyways, you are using the form object to create the `select`, so there is no need to keep `fields_for` block. Though you are using the `fields_for` to create the hidden field `user_id`, I can't see where do you have the `user_id` attribute in `UnitShiftType` Model.

So replace the fields_for block

```
<%= f.fields_for :unit_shift_type do |ff| %>
  <%= f.select :shift_type_ids, ShiftType.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id, ]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
  <%= ff.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<%= f.select :shift_type_ids, ShiftType.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

And add `shift_type_ids` to `Unit` Model's `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing:

```
<%= f.select :shift_type_ids, ShiftType.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id, ]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

with:

```
  <%= f.select :shift_type_ids, @unit.unit_shift_types.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id, ]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

But to get a real solution, we'd have to see your controller's create and/or update action. How are you adding a shift_type to a unit?

It should look SOMETHING like:

```
@unit << shift_type
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the controller#create and #update.  The problem with the solution you've provided is that I'm attempting to grab previously built ShiftTypes and associating them to a Unit.

I'm not actually saving an ID reference within Units. I'm going to be having a UnitShiftType record created for each item selected.  So if they picked Day, Night ShiftTypes. They'd have 2 records within UnitShiftType that associates to the Unit#.